# Strange content in eclipse photon views

Tags: eclipse, installation

I've just installed eclipse photon on my ubuntu 16.04 lts system

To familiarize myself with this IDE I tried to follow the 'Create Hello World application' tutorial.

On the right hand panel the following is displayed:

[image]

I see &apos &gt $quot instead of ' > "

Q:

- is this the expected behaviour, or
- an eclipse bug, or
- a ubuntu related eclipse weakness, or
- has other causes, possibly a hint to some install problems?

I've installed eclipse this way:

- downloaded the appropriate archive file from this link: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/photon/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz
- unpacked it
- started the install executable
- set the install path to /opt/eclipse

No launcher script/icon was created or installed, so I started eclipse from the command line:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: Probably just an Eclipse bug dealing with HTML character references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that has already been fixed:

[**Eclipse bug 536693** - System.out.println("Hello world!"); in cheatsheet for hello world application](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536693)

The next release, which will be released in September, will contain the bug fix.